# Hide formulas from non editors

Tags: google-sheets

The **goal** is to hide the formulas in the cells in order to show only the data to the users in the very same spreadsheet.

**Why?** Currently I'm showing some information to the teams, but the formulas contain info that these teams shouldn't be able to know.

To minimize the problem I'm importing most of the data using formulas such `IMPORTRANGE` or `QUERY` but even those methods show the URL of the original spreadsheet.

Use a Script to copy isn't a viable solution due the amount of data and frequency some those sheets receive updates.

Comment: What operations do the users need to perform?

Comment: Showing the URL of original spreadsheet should not be a problem if those users don't have access to the original spreadsheet.

Comment: @Cooper in some cases they filter the data by selecting a date of month in a list, but in all cases they interact with the spreadsheet in some way.

Comment: @Alex they do have access, otherwise the `IMPORTRANGE` will not work. As far as I know the spreadsheet from `QUERY` or `IMPORTRANGE` will search need to be accessible by the person who is running the function.